# Setting SSLContext to jdbc connection

Tags: ssl, jdbc

I want to create and configure `SSLContext` object and then make `mysql.jdbc.Driver` use it for establishing secure connection. Is there an approach for it better then custom `jdbc.Driver`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom `com.mysql.jdbc.SocketFactory` class that creates `SSLSocket`s using an `SSLSocketFactory` coming from this `SSLContext`. Then, you can pass that class name to the MySQL JDBC connector using the `socketFactory` property (see table in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)).

This needs to have a constructor with no parameters, but its `Socket connect(String host, Properties props)` method should get the JDBC properties via its `props` parameter (if you need).

Note that you should not only check the validity of your certificate, but also check that the host name matches. If you're using Java 7, this can be done like this before returning the `SSLSocket` you've just created:

```
SSLParameters sslParams = new SSLParameters();
sslParams.setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm("HTTPS");
sslSocket.setSSLParameters(sslParams);
```

(The host name matching rules for HTTPS should be sufficiently sensible for most protocols, including MySQL.)

Comment: It seems it would replace the StandardSocketFactory[1], so you would lose all features relating to timeouts, keepalive and buffersize, wouldn't you?

[1]http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/mysql/jdbc/StandardSocketFactory.java.html